# PhpDocs: Link to another method in "@deprecated" tag's description?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

Is it possible to link to another method/class/property/etc. inside my project inline inside the `@deprecated` tag? Like this:

```
/**
 * Method description
 * @deprecated 1.0 Reason for deprecation, use {@link newMethod()} instead!
 * @param string $str
 * @param string|null $str2
 * @return bool
*/
public function method($str, $str2) {
    // TODO: Code...
}

...
```

?

Comment: you can use the [@see](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/see.html) tag

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to PHPdoc.org, you could use the [@see](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/see.html#see) tag for that.

```
 /**
 * @see http://example.com/my/bar Documentation of Foo.
 * @see MyClass::$items           For the property whose items are counted.
 * @see MyClass::setItems()       To set the items for this collection.
 *
 * @return integer Indicates the number of items.
 */
function count()
{
     <...>
}
```

Also, [PHPdoc.org recommends to use @see in case of a @deprecated method](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/deprecated.html#deprecated):

> It is RECOMMENDED (but not required) to provide an additional description stating why the associated element is deprecated. If it is superceded by another method it is RECOMMENDED to add a @see tag in the same PHPDoc pointing to the new element.

But `@see` is not always required, for example ["Link to another method in @param tag's description?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75315415/8740349)

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

- PHPStorm verified:

```
    /**
     * @deprecated Instead use: {@see \Your\Namespace\YourClass::yourmethod}
     */
```

---

- vscode(intelephense) now only supports separate `@see` and class ([still an open issue](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1316)) - workaround:

```
    /**
     * @deprecated Consider using {@see \Your\Namespace\YourClass::yourmethod}
     * @see \Your\Namespace\YourClass ::yourmethod
     */
```

The "hover" seems to be still bugged [(1)](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/2183) [(2)](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/1803), but clicking on separate FQN @see link in the class works.

---

---

### Use FQN

You almost had it! But you have to prefix the method with at least the class name (and namespace), method parenthesis are optional.

**I strongly recommend to use FQN(fully qualified name) (include the namespace).**

It's not that <del>`self::`</del> doesn't work, but with FQN, you will ***greatly*** increase readability for outsiders, especially if the new method is from a different class.

If you still don't want to use FQNs, at least use the class name explicitly.

Method parenthesis are optional. (separate) `@see` seems to be more cross-IDE supported.