# PhpDocs: Link to another method in "@param" tag's description?

Tags: php, documentation, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

Is it possible to link to another method/class/property/etc of my project, inline inside the `@param` tag?

Like this:

```php
/**
 * My method's description.
 *
 * @param string $myArg Pass here result of {@link myOtherMethod()}.
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function myMethod($myArg) {
    // TODO: code here.
}

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Both `PhpDoc` (`phpDocumentor`) and `doxygen` support inline-link to other method.

#### For phpDocumentor

Use:

```
{@link myOtherMethod()}
```

Or:

```
{@link MyClass::myOtherMethod()}
```

> But unlike `doxygen`, seems inline-link is **not** everywhere supported,
> see [PhpDocs: Link to another method in "@deprecated" tag's description?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41303374/8740349)

#### For doxygen:

```
{@link #myOtherMethod}
```

Or:

```
{@link MyClass#myOtherMethod}
```

Or even just:

```
myOtherMethod()
```

> **Note** that human-readability of un-compiled docs matters,
> hence `phpDocumentor` syntax should be used, because it's more known (by `PHP` developers at least).
>
> **But** once `doxygen` supports that same `PhpDoc` syntax, it's no issue to generate docs with `doxygen`, because once docs are compiled, it does not matter with what tool they were compiled, they are readable either way.